# Android RTP. Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted.

Tags: java, android

I got an error message when trying to play around with Android RTP.

```
Error:(49, 55) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to NetworkInterface
Error:(51, 69) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to InetAddress
```

My code like this one

```
for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement(); //first error message
            for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement(); //second error message
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    ip= inetAddress.getAddress();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Object` class in stead of `Enumeration` class in your for loop?

Comment: I never tried it. How to convert it?

Comment: What is `en` variable?

Comment: Please use `Object enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();` Does it work?

Comment: @Vyacheslav please check my updated code.

Comment: Could you debug just to see what is the type of en ? And you probably forgot NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) en.nextElement(); ?

Comment: @AlexMamo I got another error messages.

Error:(51, 57) error: cannot find symbol method nextElement()
Error:(50, 77) error: cannot find symbol method hasMoreElements()
Error:(49, 43) error: cannot find symbol method nextElement()
Error:(48, 73) error: cannot find symbol method hasMoreElements()

Comment: Here the full source code, https://github.com/datomnurdin/AndroidRTP/blob/master/app/src/main/java/my/intellij/androidrtp/MainActivity.java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
```

with:

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
```

and replace:

```
for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
```

with:

```
for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
```